# Tengo un popup en la cabecera y cuando lo abro se me pone debajo del contenido de la pagina

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

tengo un popup desde el header, mi problema es que cuando pincho al popup, se me abre pero el contenido que no esta en la barra de navegacion se superpone.

Quiero que la ventana que aparece en la segunda imagen salga por encima del contenido de la pagina y pueda pinchar en ella.

Pagina sin pinchar en el boton que abre el popup:
[image: 2]

No puedo interactuar con el popup/overlay y quiero q el contenedor del overlay tenga opacidad 100%(que no se transaparente):
[image: 3]

Aparece por arriba del popup/overlay:
[image: 4]

Quiero que se vea asi pero con el contenido que este fuera del popup no pueda interactuar con el:
[image: 1]

popup:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" id="nav">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0 ms-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <button id="btn-abrir-popup" class="btn-abrir-popup">Trabajos</button>
                            <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
                                <div class="popup" id="popup">
                                    <a href="#" id="btn-cerrar-popup" class="btn-cerrar-popup"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            
                                            <a href="img1.php"><img src="img/global.jpg" id="img"></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            
                                            <a href="img1.php"><img src="img/global.jpg" id="img"></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
       </nav>
```

archivo js:

```
var btnAbrirPopup = document.getElementById('btn-abrir-popup'),
    overlay = document.getElementById('overlay'),
    popup = document.getElementById('popup'),
    btnCerrarPopup = document.getElementById('btn-cerrar-popup');

btnAbrirPopup.addEventListener('click', function(){
    overlay.classList.add('active');
    popup.classList.add('active');
});

btnCerrarPopup.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    overlay.classList.remove('active');
    popup.classList.remove('active');
});
```

css:

```
    .overlay {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        display: flex;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    
    .overlay.active {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    
    .popup {
        /* recuadro*/
        background: #F8F8F8;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        border-radius: 3px;
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        padding: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 900px;
        
        transition: .3s ease all;
        transform: scale(0.7);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .popup form .container-inputs {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    
    .popup form .container-inputs input {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        height: 52px;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 52px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
    }
```

Comment: Pon el código del popup tambien para que podamos ayudarte.
Lo más probable es que sea un error con el z-index

Comment: Añadido, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Estas usando bootstrap?

Comment: Bootstrap v5.2.0-beta1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se como estás lanzando ese popup, pero en bootstrap existe el componente [modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/) que puede servirte para ello.

Yo lo haria así, incluyendo estos divs en lugar de los divs de overlay y popup:

```
<div class="modal" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-body">
```

y al final cerrándolos.

Y luego, al final del documento, antes del `</body>`, agregaria esto para lanzarlo durante el arranque de la página:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  const myModal = new bootstrap.Modal('#exampleModal')
  myModal.show()
</script>
```

**Un consejo gratuíto**: No uses versiones beta de nada, usa siempre la última estable. Las beta tienden a cambiar en cualquier momento y no son estables.

Dejo un snippet funcional para que lo veas:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light" id="nav">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0 ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <button type="button" id="btn-abrir-popup" class="btn-abrir-popup" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Trabajos</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card" id="card-long">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XeHt.png" class="card-img-top">
    </div>
    <div class="card" id="card-short">
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
    <div class="modal-content ">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button></div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <a href="#" id="btn-cerrar-popup" class="btn-cerrar-popup"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1 class="text-center">Taladros</h1>
            <a href="img1.php"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFqq9.png" id="img"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1 class="text-center">Cortes</h1>
            <a href="img1.php"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFqq9.png" id="img"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  const myModal = new bootstrap.Modal('#exampleModal')
  myModal.show()
</script>
```

Comment: Ha funcionado con este codigo https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/    No entendia como establecer el modal con el js, ahora me toca investigar para que se vea bien, pero es mas sencillo utilizar modal, muchas gracias.

Comment: El modal se puede abrir con atributos en el botón, o bien con javascript al inicio, como ya te habia puesto en mi respuesta

Comment: Si ejecutas el snippet de mi respuesta (dale al botón EJECUTAR que aparece debajo) verás que si funciona aqui.  Si no te funciona en tu sitio ya no se.

Comment: Ya me ha funcionado con tu ejemplo, tenia un error en la referencia del button.
Ahora falta centrar el texto y que el recuadro se junte con las imagenes jajaj, lo intento a ver si lo saco.

Comment: Usa el componente Card para eso, creo que te será más practico